# TableView Cell doesn't scale equally along y-axis

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cgaffinetransform

I have tableView cells that are populated with a color in each cell. What I want is when the user taps on the cell, it "opens"/expands so that that color fills the entire screen. Currently, it only scales downwards from the cell that I click on. I also need it to scale upwards along the y-axis, each cell expanding to the top of the screen, but I'm not sure what's prohibiting it to.

```
let expandedColorView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        return view
    }()

@objc func userTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended {
            let tapLocation = sender.location(in: self.paletteTableView)

            if let tapIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: tapLocation) {
                if let tappedCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: tapIndexPath) {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
                        tappedCell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 50)
                    } )

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

UITapGestureRecognizer is declared in `tableView(cellForRowAt:)` with `cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` enabled.

I've tried changing the expandedColorView bounds `self.expandedColorView.bounds.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height` in `UIView.animate` but that doesn't change anything. I was thinking the cell's frame would need to change so that it matches the parent view frame (which I think would be tableView) but I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated!

I've attached a gif of the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If that's what you want

This is what I have done in data source extension

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "colorCell") as? ColorFulTableViewCell {
            let color = colors[Int(indexPath.row % 7)]
            cell.backgroundColor = color
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 50
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if let row = expandCell?.row, row == indexPath.row {
            return self.tableView.bounds.size.height
        }
        else {
            return 100
        }
    }
}
```

And tableView delegate extension looks like

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if self.expandCell == indexPath { return }
        else {
            self.expandCell = indexPath
        }
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**Whats happening her?**

In `heightForRowAt` of TableView data source method, I check if cell need to cover the whole tableView size by using  `if let row = expandCell?.row, row == indexPath.row {` and set its height to match the tableView height by returning `self.tableView.bounds.size.height` else I return 100

In `didSelectRowAt` I update the indexPath of cell to expand by saving it in `expandCell` and I reload the row (so that this time when height for row is called it can return `self.tableView.bounds.size.height` and I also call `scrollToRow(at` with position as `.top` to ensure my cell scrolls to top and makes itself visible completely

Because you are reloading only a specific cell, though from cost perspective its efficient, but animation might look rusty as other cells in visible indexPath array are adjusting them selves abruptly, you can always call reload Data to get much better smoother experience.

[image]

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if self.expandCell == indexPath { return }
        else {
            self.expandCell = indexPath
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and help. Questions - Is ````expandCell```` an object that I define somewhere? I get an error stating "Use of unresolved identifier 'expandCell'". And can I only expand cell if tableView scrolling is enabled? I realized after you posted that I should've been more thorough in my code because I had ````tableView.isScrollEnabled = false```` (still new to posting on SO). When I set it to true, the cells were able to scale to the top and bottom but still wonky because the cell about it will show on top of it when expanded

Comment: I made some changes to my code and it's different enough that I've posted it as a new question if you can check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61847668/scale-tableview-cell-with-cgaffinetransform-to-cover-entire-screen